# How to iterate NSArray of results into separate arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I am using [Parse](https://parse.com/) for data storage. I create a query for my Game Turn Scores which return an array in a callback like this:

```
(
"<GameTurnScore:ipPd3tKRc1:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 1;\n    TurnDifficulty = 0;\n    TurnNumber = 1;\n    TurnScore = 500;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:e3Wyo4JaKC>\";\n}",
"<GameTurnScore:AendjA9Yzq:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 6;\n    TurnDifficulty = 1;\n    TurnNumber = 2;\n    TurnScore = 48;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:UgkZDtDsVC>\";\n}",
"<GameTurnScore:ZTNmSkGae1:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 8;\n    TurnDifficulty = 2;\n    TurnNumber = 3;\n    TurnScore = 60;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:e3Wyo4JaKC>\";\n}",
"<GameTurnScore:8QbcznSa1u:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 3;\n    TurnDifficulty = 1;\n    TurnNumber = 4;\n    TurnScore = 99;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:UgkZDtDsVC>\";\n}",
"<GameTurnScore:Mj6LmdE5LY:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 8;\n    TurnDifficulty = 0;\n    TurnNumber = 5;\n    TurnScore = 60;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:e3Wyo4JaKC>\";\n}",
"<GameTurnScore:qeDWt7KFK2:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 12;\n    TurnDifficulty = 1;\n    TurnNumber = 6;\n    TurnScore = 24;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:UgkZDtDsVC>\";\n}",
"<GameTurnScore:RMRYi9fkUu:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 1;\n    TurnDifficulty = 2;\n    TurnNumber = 7;\n    TurnScore = 500;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:e3Wyo4JaKC>\";\n}",
"<GameTurnScore:Fd78iI8NGo:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 6;\n    TurnDifficulty = 1;\n    TurnNumber = 8;\n    TurnScore = 48;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:UgkZDtDsVC>\";\n}",
"<GameTurnScore:qioVUqmbEB:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 1;\n    TurnDifficulty = 2;\n    TurnNumber = 9;\n    TurnScore = 500;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:e3Wyo4JaKC>\";\n}",
"<GameTurnScore:iFLS39GqLM:(null)> {\n    GameRef = \"<Game:jGBok5ZiXM>\";\n    TotalGuesses = 1;\n    TurnDifficulty = 1;\n    TurnNumber = 10;\n    TurnScore = 300;\n    UserRef = \"<PFUser:UgkZDtDsVC>\";\n}"
)
```

I then need to separate these scores into two separate arrays. At present I separate based on the user but I would like to separate these based on the TurnNumber.

The specific part I am unsure about is inserting an emtpy index or `[NSNull null]` into an index if a turn number does not exist.

For example, I have two new `NSArrays` called `scoreBlock1` and `scoreBlock2`. If turn number 3 is missing I would like the following in `scoreBlock1`.

turnNumber1
NSNull null
turnNumber5
turnNumber7
turnNumber9

What is the best way to iterate the results array to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want null values in place of missing turns? Seems like just having them be missing would be easier to handle later. Also, how would you "know" that a turn was missing?

Comment: Thanks, I guess the reason is that I know there is an object at each 5 of the indexes. If I just add any of the turns to the new array how do I check if there is an object in the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[array addObject:[NSNull null]]` to insert a null into an array.

You can later test for the presence of a null value using `[object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]`

Comment: Thanks, I know I can use `valueForKey...` and `objectForKey` to retrieve the values I need. The question is more around how to handle when a specific turn score would be missing and to insert the null there.

Comment: If you using the slicing variant of valueForKeyPath, it will put NSNull's in for the missing values, which is how I'm interpreting your request.  If you're not looking to slice the array, but are only interested in finding missing scores, you probably want to look at filteredArrayUsingPredicate and a predicate TurnNumber = nil.

Comment: If you're trying to build up the two result arrays in a for loop, you can just `addObject:[NSNull null]`

Comment: I am not only looking for TurnNumber I also need the other data later on too, the TurnNumber in theory is just being used for splitting the array. Would you suggest the other approach?

Comment: If I have a for loop though, I can check for the turnNumber odd/even and split into the arrays but how would I know if a turnNumber is missing in the for loop?

Comment: `[object objectForKey:]` should return nil if it hasn't been assigned yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51129/discussion-between-david-and-stuartm)